# code in willTransition callback executed after model callback after a window.alert

Tags: firefox, ember.js, alert, back-button, html5-history

I recently encountered a bug with Ember.js. Basically when I click the browser back button in Firefox, Ember.js executes the code in wrong order. The code in `willTransition` callback right after the line `alert("...");` is executed after `model` callback, which should normally be executed right after `alert("...");` is returned.

The code is:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    willTransition: function(transition){
      console.log('start IndexRoute#willTransition');
      alert('See console logs');
      console.log('end IndexRoute#willTransition');
    }
  }
});
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log('start FooRoute#model');
    return [];
  }
});
```

An instruction on how to reproduce the bug can be found here: https://github.com/goooooouwa/location/blob/master/README.md

See this bug in action **with Firefox**( version 12+ on OS X, version 7+ on Windows) on JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tefoka/

Comment: This bug seems caused by [this](https://github.com/goooooouwa/location/blob/master/README.md) Firefox( version 38.0.1) bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this behaviour is [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1167575) Firefox bug.

### How this bug causes the behaviour in question

#### What's happening under the hood

1. After user hit browser back button, the URL is changed, the browser history is then changed, which triggers a `PopStateEvent`, and Ember then handles this event with `onUpdateURL()` callback
2. As the callback, Ember starts a transition by calling `this._doURLTransition('handleURL', url);`
3. Inside the transition, a Promise is created to determine the resolution of this transition. Ember schedules promises in runloop by calling `run.backburner.schedule('actions', function(){...})`, since no runloop is created, an [autorun](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/) will be created by calling `Backburner.createAutoRun()`:

```js
function createAutorun(backburner) {
  backburner.begin();
  backburner._autorun = global.setTimeout(function() {
    backburner._autorun = null; 
    backburner.end();
  });   
}
```

before the auto-created runloop ends, the following code is executed:

```
willTransition: function(transition){
  console.log('-------------- 1. start IndexRoute#willTransition -------------- ');
  alert('See console logs');
  console.log('-------------- 2. end IndexRoute#willTransition -------------- ');
}
```

when the runloop ends, the flush process begins, and the following code is executed:

```
model: function() {
  console.log('-------------- 3. start FooRoute#model -------------- ');
  return [];
}
```

#### Simplified version

The above code is essencailly the same as:

```
console.log('processing: task #1');
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('processing: task #3');
},0);
alert('See console logs');
console.log('processing: task #2');
```

The above code runs wrongly with the Firefox bug, which causes the Ember behaviour in question.